# Doubts about Windows Azure Platform Introductory Special

Tags: azure

I'm considering to join the [Windows Azure Platform Introductory Special](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/popup/popup.aspx?lang=en&locale=en-US&offer=MS-AZR-0001P), but I'm a little bit afraid of losing money with it. I don't wanna develop any fancy large scale application, I want to join just to learn Azure and do my experiments, what should I be afraid of?

In the transference, it says: "Data Transfers (per region)", what does that mean?

Can I put limits to stop the app if it goes over this plan in order to avoid get charged?

Can it be "pre pay" instead "bill pay"?

Would it be enough for a blog?

Any experiencie so far?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ligget pointed out, Azure isn't cost affect as a host for an application that can be easily deployed to a traditional shared hosting provider. Azure's target market are those that want dedicated resources without the need to micro-manage the infrasture and the capability to easily scale up/down based on demand.

That said, here's the answers to the questions you posted:
Data Transfers are based on bandwidth in and out of the hosting data center. bandwidth for communication occuring within components (SQL Azure, Windows Azure, Azure Storage, etc...) in the same datacenter are not billable.

Your usage is not currently capped when the free quotas are used up. However, you will recieved warning emails when those items approach their usage threadsholds.

There is the option to pay your subscription using a PO, but the minimum threshold for most of these operations is $500/month. So as a hobbyist, its unlikely you're wanting that route.

The introductory special does not provide enough resources for hosting a 24x7 personal blog. That level includes only 25hrs of compute resources. Each hour a single instance of your application is deployed will count against this, even if the application received no traffic. Think of it like renting office space. You still pay rent on the office even if there are no customers there.

All this said, there's still much to be learned with the introductory special. The azure development tools allows you to work with Windows Azure and Azure storage locally and get a feel for how they work. The introductory special then lets you deploy those solutions so you can see what works and what doesn't (not everything that works locally works hosted).

Comment: I'd understood that in Azure you pay only what you use, so I guessed that those 25 hours won't count when the app is in idle because nobody is requesting a page. All my happiness went away :( The message I got form the book I'm reading abut Azure is "you pay only what you use", and considering that even IIS could shutdown an AppDomain when it's not used... I didn't expect this. Thanks!

Comment: It is a statement that assumes a certain level of understanding of how Azure allocates resources. The concept of the VM being reserved isn't something that folks immediately go to. We're too used to think in terms of CPU cycles and not in terms of app hosting. :P

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you host your blog somewhere else - it's a waste of resources running it on Azure and you'll find much cheaper options. A recently introduced extra small instance would be a better choice in this case, but AFAIK it is charged separately as of now, e.g. even when you have an MSDN subscription those extra small instance hours do not count towards free Azure hours that come with the subscription.

There is no pre-pay option I know of and it's not possible to stop the app automatically. It'll be running until the deployment is deleted (beware! even if suspended/stopped the deployment will continue to accrue charges). I believe you will be sent a notification shortly before reaching your free hours threshold.

Be aware that when launching more than 1 instance you are charged for every hour of every instance combined. This can happen for example when you have more than one role in your Azure project (1 web role + 1 worker role - a separate instance will be started for each role).

Data trasfer means your entire data trasfer: blobs/Table storage/queues (transfers between your hosted service and storage account inside the same data center are free) + whatever data is transfered in/out of your hosted application, e.g. when somebody visits your pages. When you create storage accounts and hosted services in Azure you will specify a region that will be hosting your account/app - hosting in Asia is slightly more expensive than in Europe/U.S.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to contact Microsoft with these questions.

Comment: well, what I want is to find somebody that has used it and could give me some advice from him experience